# Component mount issue: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to insert/mount a component into a DOM, but getting an error saying 'Target container is not a DOM element'. I guess 'mounthere' is not getting recognized in the DOM. Where can i place this code correctly?
`ReactDOM.createRoot(React.createElement(Comp1, document.getElementById("mounthere")));`

DOM code:

```
const DOM1 = () => {
ReactDOM.createRoot(React.createElement(Comp1, document.getElementById("mounthere")));

    function1()
    {
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
        return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div class = "DOM1-container">
            <Header />
            <div class = "dom1">
                <div id = "mounthere">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Component code:

```
class Comp1 extends React.Component {
    content1 = () => {
      });
    };
    
    componentDidMount() {
      this.content1();
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div id="div1">
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you have an element with id `mounthere` ?

Comment: yes, in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are trying to mount Comp1 into the element with id "mounthere". However, this element may not have been rendered yet when ReactDOM.createRoot() is called. useEffect can solve your problem

```
 useEffect(() => {
    ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("mounthere")).render(<Comp1 />);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Why would you want to create a second Root? If you're already using a component, no need to create another Root.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `React.createElement` since `Comp1` is already a component.

Just move the `createRoot` outside of the class, and pass `<Comp1 />` to the `render()` call:

```js
class Comp1 extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div id="div1">
          FooBar
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("mounthere")
).render(<Comp1 />);
```

```html
<div id="mounthere"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks but i am choosing the other one as answer. +1

Comment: Np, kinda strange to use createRoot in a useEffect, that makes no sense.